# Html text to JQuery with line break

Tags: php, jquery, html, line, break

following example:

1. I got a php function which generates me some text with "\n\r" at the end
2. The output is generated in a html div, which is hidden
3. JQuery takes the text of the div with innerText
4. Writes it in a other div

That's what i do in the moment.
The line break in php has no effect to the "end div".

**How can i get the line break at the end div?**

Regards

EDIT: With a `<br>` in my php function an alert works fine. So the failure is at point 4.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("statistiktextdiv").innerText;
$jq( "#statistiktext" ).text(text);
```

```html
<div id="statistiktext"></div>

function showsomething(){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($statistik); $i++){
        echo $something[$i]['number'] . "<br>";
    }
}
?>

<div id="statistiktextdiv" style="visibility: hidden;"><?php showsomething(); ?></div>
```

Comment: Can you insert your code here ?

Comment: @jerome Yeah, i did.

Comment: See also [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden But the alert works. Javascript knows the line break. Or i am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How eould you like the `\n\r` to manifest itself? You can only actually see it when you inspect code, because browser ignore `\n\r` otherwise

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek I replaced the \n\r with <br>. In the alert i can see the line break. When i write it back in a div, there is no line break

Comment: You mean there is no `<br>` (it should be `<br />` by the way) in the div?

Comment: Yeah there is no <br/> in the div. All in one line. I added the <br/> at the php funciton, same problem.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek You statement about using `<br />` is false. `<br>` is HTML. `<br />` is XHTML. Nothing wrong with using `<br>`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I was lied to. I checked what you said. You are right. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript String.replace method to change the `\n\r` to a `<br>` tag so the browser will render it.

```
alteredText = originalText.replace( '\n\r', '<br>' );
```

You can see that the console and alert windows treat these special characters the way a text editor does, but they are not rendered as breaks in html.

```js
originalText = "line 1\n\r\line 2";
alteredText = originalText.replace( '\n\r', '<br>' );

console.log( originalText );
console.log( '---------' );
console.log( alteredText );

$('body').append( originalText );
$('body').append( '<hr>' );
$('body').append( alteredText );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something interessting:
When i write the text from JS to an textarea, its working!

So the problem seems to be the `<div>`.
I tryed with a random tag like `<random>`, it's not working.

Any ideas what is wrong?